# 400VDC to 220AC PWM inverter MOSFET damage

Tags: power-electronics

I am using EG8010 chip to create a 400V DC to 220AC inverter which does not use bulky transformers. I have used the exact same circuit shown in the data sheet of EG8010. The circuit works ok and output a good sine wave for low input voltages (I have tested it upto 80V). When I input 400V's however, the circuit seem to be very unstable and for no apparent reason, MOSFET's gets damaged. This happens even if there is no load connected to the output. The MOSFET's I am using are the ones recommended in the datasheet (IRF840) which have 500V mas VDS.

I've read in a different forum that this could be due to voltage spikes due to inductance of the load (for example the filter inductor). Could this be the case? If so, what would be the best solution avoid such spikes?

Schematics:
https://www.lz2gl.com/data/power-inverter-3kw/eg8010_datasheet_en.pdf
Please refer to Figure 6‐2 in that doc.

Comment: Plenty of room for speculations, please provide schematics and signal screen shots of the working unit at 80 V. A picture of the device often can help as well

Comment: Using a 500Vds MOSFET with inductors at 400V is like taking a [Yugo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yugo) onto the [Autobahn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobahn) and wondering why it dies at 150km/h.  i.e. for real-world performance, at least *double* the ratings is a really good idea.

Comment: _”The MOSFET's I am using are the ones recommended in the datasheet (IRF840) which have 500V mas VDS.”_ Ouch! Think 700+ V.

Comment: The physical layout of the circuit is as important as the schematic. Post detailed high resolution pictures of your assembled PCB.

Comment: all, I updated the question with a link to schematic.

Comment: There is no bus link capacitor shown. Should be one with several hundred uF and one or more low impedance film types.